# When executing bash script via "docker exec" Docker looks for script on host machine, but not in container

Tags: bash, docker, git-bash

I'm trying to execute a script inside Docker container with the command:

```
docker exec <my-container> bash -c "/tmp/scripts/script.sh"
```

For this reason I use Git Bash on Windows 10. Unfortunately, this returns an error

```
bash: C:/Users/<windows-user>/AppData/Local/Temp/scripts/script.sh: No such file or directory
```

So I can easily conclude that Git Bash tries to find the script on host Windows machine, but not inside the container (which is expected behavior).

At the same time, PowerShell runs this command as expected - script is executed inside the container.

What could be the reason of such behavior and how to solve it?

---

Note. I've found a workaround:

```
commandtorun='bash -c "/tmp/scripts/script.sh"'
docker exec <my-container> $commandtorun
```

and it worked. But I still interested why the initial command not working.

Answer (score 4):

> I still interested why the initial command not working.

Probably because the bash interpret the arguments passed to docker exec.

- In the first case, there are 3, including `"/tmp/scripts/script.sh"`, whose `/tmp` is reinterpreted as `C:/Users/<windows-user>/AppData/Local/Temp/`
- In the second case, there is only one `'bash -c "/tmp/scripts/script.sh"'`, using string quotes (`'`), and passed as-is to `docker exec`.
  The all command is then executed in the context of the container, and in that context, `/tmp/scripts/script.sh` is a valid path.

Comment: Is there is a way to influence on such interpretation? I assume this is all because of Windows OS as far as all examples and documentation suggest the 1st form of command. An basically PowerShell can run it, so what causes the different command interpretation in Git Bash..?

Comment: Try adn use single quotes: `bash -c '/tmp/scripts/script.sh'`: that should avoid any re-interpretation by the bash shell.

Comment: @VonC thanks single quote works and it does the job